# Text segmentation for Tamil language with Java Eclipse

Tags: java, unicode, tamil

In Java Eclipse, when the words are segmented,the Tamil words gets splitted as below

Example:

```
படிகஅமைப்பு  = பட +   ிகஅமைப்பு
```

instead of

```
படிகஅமைப்பு =  படி + கஅமைப்பு
```

The Tamil font "Latha" is used. Kindly help me to resolve this issue